# Django update other user account fields through Model Form (when logged in as admin)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication, modelform

I am building a django project that allows users to singup and then post projects.
Apps include a 'users' app and a 'projects' app.
I am using @signals so that 'users' create/edit a Profile and the @signals ensure that the underlying django User model is always in synch with the Profile model contained in the 'users' app.
I have one Profile for the superuser and this is set up to not only access its own 'user profile' and 'project posts' that it may post, but is also set up to review the projects posted by other users before they can be seen in the public feed of 'project posts'.
In the Project model (within the projects app models.py) i have a field called 'is_approved' with a default value of false and 'project posts' are only visible in the public feed after the superadmin has used its template view of a model form to update 'is_approved' from False to True.
Each 'project post' includes a Profile field as a foreign key (one-to-many)

The above is working very well - as the superuser can be the sessionid authenticated user and yet update the 'project posts' that belong to a different profile.

My problem now is trying to do the above when logged in as the superuser, but attempting to update fields in other Profiles (such as 'is_accepted' from False to True) through a model Form.
I need to do this so that when a Profile is edited it can have its 'is_accepted' status returned to False, so that the superuser can then review before the Profile returns to the public list of Profiles.
With the code below, I first check that it is the superuser attempting to access the route to this 'admin' template and if not boot them back to their account page. I use the 'profilej' variable for this.
I then get the Profile that needs to be updated and I use the 'profileq' variable for this.
When I print these out they contain the appropriate values.  'profilej' contains the superuser  and  'profileq' contains the Profile to be edited.

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def editAccountBoss(request, pk):
    profilej = request.user.profile
    print(profilej)
    if profilej.bossnum != 9999:
        return redirect('account')
    profileq = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    print(profileq)
    form = ProfileFormBoss(instance=profileq)
```

In the last line of the above code, I am passing the 'profileq' to the form variable.
It is then this same 'form' that I am validating and saving in the code below.
The Problem I keep getting is that the 'superuser' (who is the sessionid authenticated user) is getting updated instead of the Profile that opens up and is edited.
This 'edit profile' code works fine when any sessionid authenticated profile/user is updating their ownn profile so i dont think its trying to create a duplicate and yet I am getting the following error and behind the scenes before the error, the fields of 'profileq' are being updated to the superuser 'profilej'.

here is the rest of the code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProfileFormBoss(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profileq)
   
    websocial = request.POST['social_website']
    #print(websocial[0:8])
    if websocial[0:8] != "https://" and websocial != "":
        messages.error(request, 'Use full web address format: 
         https://www.example.com')
   
    elif form.is_valid():
        profileq = form.save(commit=False)
        profileq.is_accepted = True
        form.save()

        return redirect('acc-boss-dash-profiles')

context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'users/profile_formboss.html', context)
```

This is the error I keep getting.  I have messed around with a few different alternatives (i.e. profileq.save()  etc.)  but keep getting same error:

**IntegrityError at /profiles/edit-account/
UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username**

And here is the underlying Model Form:

```
class ProfileFormBoss(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['name', 'email', 'username',
              'location', 'bio', 'short_intro', 'profile_image', 'is_accepted', 'social_github', 'social_linkedin', 'social_twitter', 'social_youtube', 'social_website']
    exclude = ['social_github', 'social_linkedin', 'social_twitter',
              'social_youtube'] 
    help_texts = {
        'social_website': 'https://www.example.com',
    }

    widgets = {
        'isaccepted': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    }


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProfileFormBoss, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    for name, field in self.fields.items():
        field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})
```

ADDED below is the Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
bossnum = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
short_intro = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='profiles/', default="profiles/user-default.png")
social_github = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
social_twitter = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
social_linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
social_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
social_website = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.username)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['created']

@property
def imageURL(self):
    try:
        url = self.profile_image.url
    except:
        url = ''
    return url
```

**ADDED below** is code from a Dashboard template that displays a list of Profiles (that need approval by the admin Profile).
The following 'a' tag is displayed with each Profile in the list of Profile cards.
The 'a' tag successfully opens the url 'edit-account-boss' with the correct Profile displayed (via the 'profilex.id' being passed to 'pk' in the 'editAccountBoss' view)

```
 <a class="tag tag--pill tag--main settings__btn" href="{% url 'edit-account-boss' profilex.id %}"><i class="im im-edit"></i> Edit</a>
```

**ADDED below** is the form from the template that opens when an above 'a' tag is clicked  (....this is the form with/causing the original error and problem of updating the admin Profile instead of the user Profile intended to be updated):

**NOTE: following comment by @Chris** , i noticed that the action attribute should perhaps be 'edit-account-boss' in lieu of 'edit-account'.   This may be the solution but at present causes another error.  If the following action attribute is updated to 'edit-account-boss', then clicking an above 'a' tag, gives this error immediately:
*NoReverseMatch at /profiles/edit-accountboss/5195f3ed-4d83-40c6-a3d7-d31da603c47c/
Reverse for 'edit-account-boss' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profiles/edit\-accountboss/(?P[^/]+)/\Z']*

```
<form class="form" action="{% url 'edit-account' %}" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form__field">
                <label for="formInput#text">{{field.label}} </label>
                {{field}}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <input class="btn btn--sub btn--lg  my-md" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

**ADDED below are the urls (including:  'edit-account' and 'edit-account-boss'):**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('login/', views.loginUser, name="login"),
path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
path('register/', views.registerUser, name="register"),

path('', views.profiles, name="profiles"),
path('profile/<str:pk>/', views.userProfile, name="user-profile"),
path('account/', views.userAccount, name="account"),
path('account-bossdash/', views.accountBossDash, name="acc-boss-dash"),
path('account-bossdashprofiles/', views.accountBossDashProfiles, name="acc-boss-dash-profiles"),

path('edit-account/', views.editAccount, name="edit-account"),
path('edit-accountboss/<str:pk>/', views.editAccountBoss, name="edit-account-boss"),

path('create-skill/', views.createSkill, name="create-skill"),
path('update-skill/<str:pk>/', views.updateSkill, name="update-skill"),
path('delete-skill/<str:pk>/', views.deleteSkill, name="delete-skill"),

path('inbox/', views.inbox, name="inbox"),
path('message/<str:pk>/', views.viewMessage, name="message"),
path('create-message/<str:pk>/', views.createMessage, name="create-message"),
```

]

Comment: What happens if you remove the ```instance=profileeq``` in the line directly after ```if request.method == 'POST'```?

Comment: thanks for your response - unfortunately same error

Comment: I believe your app is trying to create a new user with the data of your form. You need to pass the instance of the profile you want to update to your form. Currently your form does not 'know' who to update.

Comment: BTW: After calling ```form.save(commit=False)``` you need to save the returned object with ```profileq.save()``` and not the form.

Comment: Try adding ```pk``` to the fields of your form

Comment: @Chris - thanks - Ive been trying to research adding pk to the fields of the form....are you able to add an example how?

Comment: Please share your models

Comment: @Chris - the Profile model is added, thank you.  (the first line of code has lost its correct 'tab' position when pasting in)

Comment: Currently I cannot reproduce your error, your code seems to work. Please add your template, maybe there is an issue there.

Comment: @Chris - template/s and urls added.  Thankyou

Comment: @Chris - you solved this - thankyou!!  (i.e.   action="{% url 'edit-account-boss' profileq.id %}" )  - and - 'profileq.save()'  -  will you post the answer so I can give it the green tick.  Thankyou!!!

Answer (score 0):

@Chris - you solved this - thankyou!! (i.e. action="{% url 'edit-account-boss' profileq.id %}" ) - and - 'profileq.save()' - will you post the answer so I can give it the green tick. Thankyou!!!

```html
<form class="form" action="{% url 'edit-account-boss' profileq.id %}" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                <div class="form__field">
                    <label for="formInput#text">{{field.label}} </label>
                    {{field}}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <input class="btn btn--sub btn--lg  my-md" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

Then also in the view, instead of form.save() it needed profileq.save()

```html
        elif form.is_valid():
            profileq = form.save(commit=False)
            profileq.save()
```